# PdfViewController.scroll Position not working with UIWebview in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios4, pdf, uiwebview, ios5

I have an app which scrolls through Pdf files using buttons and an index within a UIWebview. It uses the code PdfViewController.scrollPosition to move to specified position's within the Pdf file. The app has been working fine and was sent to iTunes months ago but recently I have upgraded to Xcode 4 and when I try to run my app using the Ios 5 simulator the positioning will not work.

What has changed in the new Ios 5 that prevents the above code from working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered via another similar question I posted. The reason that it now doesn't work, is that IOS 5 does not support Javascript (Thank you Apple). You can use a different method to navigate through your Pdf by using webView.scrollView to move through your Pdf pages.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question. Below is the answer. Hope it solves your problem.
You can use UIWebView's Scrollview for navigation as Javascript is no more supported in IOS5: Below is a my code worked fine for me.PdfViewController is a webview

```
    [PdfViewController.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y)];
```

The contentOffset accepts a CGPoint as argument. Here x and y are integer values representing the scrollPosition. If you want to get current x and y co-ordinates for webView, below is the code which you can use:

```
NSInteger x = PdfViewController.scrollView.contentOffSet.x;
NSInteger y = PdfViewController.scrollView.contentOffset.y;
```

Note: ScrollView is introduced in IOS 5 and will not work on earlier IOS versions. Javascript function are available for earlier versions. So you can check for device version and implement code accordingly.